# gather in tabular with amsart

Tags: tables, amsart

How do I use gather in tabulars with the amsart document class?

Trying the following will not render the second column:

```latex
\documentclass[draft]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{1in} p{1in}}
{\begin{gather*}
a
\end{gather*}}&
{\begin{gather*}
b
\end{gather*}}\\
{\begin{gather*}
c
\end{gather*}}&
{\begin{gather*}
d
\end{gather*}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I do not have to use amsart or tabular, but the book I am learning from "More Math Into LaTeX" has so far been presenting with them.

Comment: that's .....  unexpected....  Thanks for the clear test file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Somewhat unfortunately `amsart` forces the `amsmath` displays to be "full width" ie `\columnwidth` even if they are in a narrow `p` column (or a `\parbox`)  this resets `\fullwidth` to use the current `\hsize` in the p column.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{
>{\def\fullwidthdisplay{\displayindent0pt \displaywidth\hsize}}p{1in}
>{\def\fullwidthdisplay{\displayindent0pt \displaywidth\hsize}}p{1in}
}
{\begin{gather*}
a
\end{gather*}}&
{\begin{gather*}
b
\end{gather*}}\\
{\begin{gather*}
c
\end{gather*}}&
{\begin{gather*}
d
\end{gather*}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for the clear test file, made this easy to find.

Comment: What about using `gathered` from `mathtools`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Zarko has an answer (deleted) that suggests that but the question was not, "what else would work?" but "why does this perfectly reasonable markup that works in the standard classes not work in in amsart?" I would say it is a bug in the AMS classes.